# How to take backup of multiple stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I understand that we can use 
    `git stash show -p > stash.diff` to take backup of a stash.

Now I want to take backup of at least 20 stashes. What's a good way to take backup of all the stashes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This snippet will list the IDs of all your existing stashes, and then create separate diff files for each.

```
for stash in `git stash list | awk -F':' '{print $1}'`
do
    git stash show $stash -p > $stash.diff
done
```

Comment: Awesome.. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will store all stashes under a filename similar to the stash commit message.
Disallowed file name characters are replaced by '_'.

```
for sha in $(git rev-list -g stash)
do
  git show -p $sha > "\`git show -s --format=%B --max-count=1 $sha  | sed 's/[/:\\?*+%]/_/g'\`.patch"
done
```

In the following version I only use the first line of the stash message for the file name:

```
for sha in $(git rev-list -g stash)
do
  git show -p $sha > "\`git show -s --pretty=format:'%s' $sha  | sed 's/[/:\\?*+%]/_/g'\`.patch";
done
```